# Stacking CSS centered on a basic HTML page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stack a PNG directly on top of another PNG.  The first PNG (logo2) is intended to lay directly on top of the second PNG (form2) - both to be centered.  I have tweaked and messed with everything and I still seem to overlooking something major that will get me what I need.  My code is this:

```
  html{
     background: url(images/bg4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     }

  #main{
     background: url(images/logo2.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
     margin: 8% auto 0 auto;
     padding: 138px 71px 0 142px;
     width: 1014;
     height: 228px;
     position: relative;
    }


  #main form {
      margin: 13% auto 0 auto;
      width: 806px;
      height: 262px;
      background: url(images/form2.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
      position: relative;
    }
```

Would it be more prudent that I don't wrap my form around main, or is my fault in my margin/padding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jsFiddle will show you how:

http://jsfiddle.net/NLb2J/

Use Absolute position and z-index